# Expect expression not to throw any error using Chai

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js, chai

I have a function

```
export function getFileContent(path: string): any {
    const content = readFileSync(path);
    return JSON.parse(content.toString());
}
```

If I want to check if the expression `getFileContent(meteFile)` throws some definite error I should write something like

```
expect(getFileContent(meteFile)).to.throw(new SyntaxError('Unexpected token } in JSON at position 82'));
```

But is there a way to check if the expression doesn't raise any error?

I tried this

```
expect(getFileContent(metaFile)).not.to.throw();
```

But got the error

```
AssertionError: expected { Object (...) } to be a function
```

So how can I check if the function call doesn't throw any error?

Comment: Hm.. I don't know if it will help but chai has a `assert.doesNotThrow` method. See this https://www.chaijs.com/api/assert/#method_doesnotthrow and look for the method.

Comment: @KnowYourElements I think, that's what I need.  Thanks.
If you write your answer I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the function call doesn't throw an error using
`assert.doesNotThrow` method

Here is an example from the documentation

```
assert.doesNotThrow(fn, 'Any Error thrown must not have this message');
assert.doesNotThrow(fn, /Any Error thrown must not match this/);
assert.doesNotThrow(fn, Error);
assert.doesNotThrow(fn, errorInstance);
```

For further understanding checkout it's documentation: [assert.doesNotThrow](https://www.chaijs.com/api/assert/#method_doesnotthrow)

Comment: In my case, it should be just `assert.doesNotThrow(fn);` 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using `expect`, so then you can use `expect(fn).to.not.throw` to make sure it doesn't throw an error.

```js
expect(myFn).to.not.throw(); // makes sure no errors are thrown
expect(myFn).to.not.throw(SomeCustomError, "the message I expect in that error"); // not recommended by their docs
```

You should probably look at [the docs for this](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_throw).